# How can I register for Notification Categories?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to register for categories but for some reason I cannot do it on my iPhone but it works on simulator? I use the following code to register and then I check to see what categories I subscribed to. When I check while running my app on my iPhone it says 0 and when I check on simulator it says 1.

```
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "SNOOZE_ACTION",
                                            title: "Snooze",
                                            options: .foreground)
    let expiredCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "TIMER_EXPIRED",
                                                 actions: [snoozeAction],
                                                 intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                 options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.setNotificationCategories([expiredCategory])
```

I then check with

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationCategories { categories in
            print("These are the categories\(categories.count)")
            print(categories.description)
        }
```

I have not clue what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, I am using this and its working for me.

```
func notificationSetup()
{
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
   {
     let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.delegate = self
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.badge,.sound]) { granted,error in
      if (error == nil) {
       UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      }
    } 
    let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "SNOOZE_ACTION", title: "Snooze", options: [.foreground, .authenticationRequired])
    let categoryOptions = UNNotificationCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0)
    let expiredCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "TIMER_EXPIRED", actions: [snoozeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: categoryOptions)
    let categories = Set([expiredCategory])
    center.setNotificationCategories(categories)

   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but this is not working on a real iPhone. This did work or a simulator though... it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Can you show more code as I did the same thing in all and its working pretty fine.